How to solve package "encoding/json" ERROR in Jenkins?
I'm trying to scan my GoLang/Angular project. I used gosec to scan the GoLang part, but this error always occurs:

/usr/local/go/bin/gosec ./...
[gosec] 2024/07/08 10:14:19 Including rules: default
[gosec] 2024/07/08 10:14:19 Excluding rules: default
[gosec] 2024/07/08 10:14:19 Import directory: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ang-go/server
2024/07/08 10:14:20 internal error: package "encoding/json" without types was imported from "command-line-arguments"

This is the initial stage:
             stage('Install Go') { steps { dir('/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ang-go/server/') {
                sh '/usr/local/go/bin/go version'
                sh '/usr/local/go/bin/go build -o myapp'
                sh '/usr/local/go/bin/go get -u github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3'
                sh '/usr/local/go/bin/go test'
                sh '/usr/local/go/bin/gosec ./...' 
               
                
            } 
        }
    }

I tried to clean cash and install dependecies with this stage:

  stage('Install Go Dependencies') {
            steps {
                dir('/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ang-go/server') {
                    sh '/usr/local/go/bin/go clean -modcache'
                    sh '/usr/local/go/bin/go mod tidy'
                    sh '/usr/local/go/bin/go mod vendor'
                }
            }
        }

I also tried to upgrade  golang.org/x/tools/go/packages with this stage :
stage('Upgrade Go Packages') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh '/usr/local/go/bin/go get -u golang.org/x/tools/go/packages'
                    sh '/usr/local/go/bin/go mod tidy'
                }
            }
        }

After trying these solutions, nothing has changed; the error remains the same, and I'm expecting to see the result of the scan
PS: the go version is: go version go1.22.3 linux/amd64

You may try to update your golang.org/x/tools to its latest version, as suggested here and here

Thank you but It didn't work
